# Cucumber gherkin use different data files in the same scenario

Tags: cucumber, qaf

Really hope someone can help on this.

Is it possible to use 2 different external data files in the "Examples" in cucumber? like below:

@play_movie

Scenario Outline: play a video on the web site

```
When I choose a movie by "<movie_name>" and play

Examples: {'datafile' : 'src/main/resources/data/testData.xls' , 'sheetName' : 'movie_demo'}
```

There is one data file in this scenario, but what if I want to use 2 or more different data files in this scenario. Is it possible to do that in cucumber?

I'm using Java as the coding language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no, you can use only one external source at a time. You can paremeterize it but still it will be one source as result.

However, it's not that you can't do! You can have your [custom data provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html) which can read multiple sources and returns test data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes I can use custom data provider to do that. I asked because I want to make the feature file looks simpler for data provider. Thanks again.

Comment: if you are using custom data provider with gherking add `'dataProvider':'my-custom-dp'
'dataProviderClass':'my.project.impl.CustomDataProvider'` in example and in BDD2 as meta data `@dataProvider:my-custom-dp 
@dataProviderClass:my.project.impl.CustomDataProvider`